# Do Virgina and Connecticut have the death penalty for those who work on Sunday?

Tags: united-states, law, law-enforcement

A Brazilian Seventh-Day Pastor called Samuel Ramos claims in this [sermon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBmPz3TLT5U) that Virginia and Connecticut have had the death penalty for those who work on Sundays since 1610:

> [5:30] Porém, existem 2 Estados Americanos, que são Virginia e Connecticut.
>   Estes estados possuem pena de morte para aqueles que trabalham aos domingos.
>   Isto é interessante pois eu morava no Estado de Virginia onde existia a pena de morte para aqueles que trabalhavam aos domingos.
>   Depois eu fui transferido para Connecticut que é o outro estado que possui pena de morte para aqueles que trabalham aos domingos.

> [06:00] Então você deve estar se perguntando: Existe  realmente alguém que tenha sido morto por trabalhar aos domingos?
>   A resposta é Não.
>   Porque estas leis, por exemplo a lei da Virgina, foi aprovada em 1610.
>   Esta lei existe, porém não está sendo aplicada.
>   Porém a lei existe.
>   A lei está guardada.
>   E no momento certo esta lei será aplicada.

Which roughly translates to:

> [5:30] However, I would like to speak about 2 American States, which are Virginia and Connecticut.
>   These states have the death penalty for those who work on Sundays.
>   This is interesting because I lived in the state of Virginia where there was the death penalty for those who worked on Sundays.
>   Then I was transferred to Connecticut, which is another death row state for those who work on Sundays.

> [06:00] So you must be wondering: Is there really someone who has been killed for working on Sundays?
>   The answer is NO.
>   Because these laws, for example the Virginia law, were passed in 1610.
>   This law exists, but it is not being enforced.
>   But the law exists.
>   The law is kept.
>   And at the right time this law will be applied.

The same claim is also repeated in a brazilian [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WpW8UPZb2w) called "Leis Dominicais no Brasil. (Documentário Integral). Blue Law - Brazil"
but Youtube has muted the audio part for some unknow reason and I can't find the original video

How much of this claim is trustable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true that the death penalty was available to punish people who worked on Sunday in Connecticut and Virginia.

In Connecticut (specifically the [New Haven Colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Haven_Colony), not the entire state), according to [Yale Law Journal vol. 7](https://books.google.com/books?id=U4QfAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22shall%20be%20put%20to%20death%20that%20all%20others%20may%20fear%20and%20shun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf6sCiqtHRAhWrwVQKHaa9Bb8Q6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22shall%20be%20put%20to%20death%20that%20all%20others%20may%20fear%20and%20shun%22&f=false) (October 1897), as of 1656 the law read:

> Whosoever shall profane the Lord's day, or any part of it, either by sinful servile work, or by unlawful sport, recreation, or otherwise, whether wilfully or in a careless neglect, shall be duly punished by fine, imprisonment, or corporally...But if the court upon examination, by clear and satisfying evidence, find that the sin was proudly, presumptiously, and with a high hand committed against the known command and authority of the blessed God, such person therein despising and reproaching the Lord, **shall be put to death**, that all others may fear and shun such provoking rebellious courses

For more information about Connecticut, see [The true-blue laws of Connecticut and New Haven and the false blue-laws invented by the Rev. Samuel Peters](https://archive.org/details/truebluelawsofco00trumiala) (1876).

The Virginia [law](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkZNonFbpB8C&pg=PA29&dq=%22whipt;+and+for+the+third,+to+suffer+death%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0ipqowNHRAhUl6YMKHVfICgYQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22whipt%3B%20and%20for%20the%20third%2C%20to%20suffer%20death%22&f=false), from 1610, didn't mention work specifically, but said that upon the third offense of not attending church service both morning and afternoon on the Sabbath, the punishment was "**to suffer death**".

In Virginia we still have [some prohibitions on hunting on Sunday](https://www.dgif.virginia.gov/hunting/hunting-on-sundays/faq/), but the other blue laws have been repealed.  See the 1988 article [END OF ERA VA. BLUE LAWS OVERTURNED](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1988/09/24/end-of-era-va-blue-laws-overturned/973256a3-30c9-46b3-a461-534e0c954c47/?utm_term=.fa860c509432) which says:

> Yesterday's decision erases a law that survived from 1610 to 1960 with few changes

Comment: Is the Connecticut law still on the books?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed no, and the one in the answer never applied to the whole state, only the New Haven Colony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Haven_Colony There is a famous fake document Connecticut Blue Laws faked in the late 1700s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Laws_(Connecticut) See also this 2012 article http://www.ctbites.com/home/2012/5/17/blue-laws-officially-end-sunday-may-20th.html

Comment: @DavePhD, this should probably appear in the answer.